# NO JSON Result from Spring3 MVC DispatcherServlet due to AOP Configuration

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc, spring-aop

When we configure Spring AOP the JSON Results disappear for : AOPExression1

```
<aop:pointcut id="dmhMethodExecution"
            expression="within(com.aditya.dmh..*)" />
```

So I added an exclusion for : AOPExpression1 as AOpExpression2

```
<aop:pointcut id="dmhMethodExecution"
   expression="within(com.aditya.dmh..*) 
        and !within(com.aditya.dmh.controller..*)" />
```

in the ASPECTJ Expression 
Still I donot see my JSON results from the controller which is a restful implementation.

```
package com.aditya.dmh.controller;

@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

private EmployeeServiceInterface employeeService;

@Autowired
public void setEmployeeService(EmployeeServiceInterface employeeService) {
    this.employeeService = employeeService;
}

@RequestMapping("/employeeservices/1/allemployees.view")
public @ResponseBody Result<EmployeeModel> getEmployees(){
    return employeeService.getEmployees(0, 10);

}
}
```

When I use log4j for the DEBUG messages I see the following:

```
15:37:04.214 [http-8090-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView  returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dmhServiceDispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling

15:37:04.214 [http-8090-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

When I remove the AOP the JSON results start to appear and I see that the additional Debug Message.

```
17:11:36.270 [http-8090-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor - Written [com.aditya.Result@8a85268] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@62ba2e48]
```

Looking at the Spring forums I understand that the Convertor is automatically configured when the

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

is used.

Is my problem of configuring AOP have anything to do with the RequestResponseBodymethodProcessor not being called.

Does this have anything to do with the proxies created around my controller when I use AOPExpression1. Why would an exclusion as in AOPExpression2 still have the problem.

Anyhelp would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I belive that to intercept a request to a controller you should do it with MVC interceptors and not with aspects. What I did is to put into the applicationContext.xml this:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/employeeservices/1/allemployees.view"/>
        <bean class="com.aditya.dmh.interceptor.ResultInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Now, the class ResultInterceptor is where you put the code you want to be done, for instance:

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    log.info("--- preHandle --- ");

    return true;
}
```

At least this is the way I did it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a speculation:

I think what is happening is a CGLIB based dynamic proxy is getting created for your controller (although you have excluded it explicitly in your new pointcut expression), if this happens then `@RequestMapping` annotations are not correctly detected(by `) and so the controller is not there to handle your REST request.

Can you try a few things:

1. Have an interface for the controller with the exact same methods that the controller handles, and put the `@RequestMapping` annotations there, this will handle cases where the dynamic proxy is created and should work as expected even if the dynamic proxy gets created..
2. Play around a little more with your pointcut expression to see why a proxy for you controller may be getting created.

Answer (score 0):

THE SOLUTION FOR OUR PROBLEM IN THIS CONTEXT

We found out that the whole thing was with the Around Advice in AOP Configuration that we have had.

Before Fix

```
public void logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    joinPoint.proceed();
    long totalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

    log.debug(buildLogMessage(new StringBuilder().append(METHOD_AROUND_ID)
            .append("[").append(totalTime).append("] ").toString(),
            joinPoint));
    return returnValue;
}
```

After Fix

```
public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Object returnValue = joinPoint.proceed();
    long totalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

    log.debug(buildLogMessage(new StringBuilder().append(METHOD_AROUND_ID)
            .append("[").append(totalTime).append("] ").toString(),
            joinPoint));
    return returnValue;
}
```

the void effectively made sure that the Response Object sent by the logAround was not passed on back to the RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor

Once we had it captured & returned the cglib proxies sent the response back to the processor & had the response sent back to the client.